# React hook form - onsubmit with data from usestate

Tags: reactjs

on handleSubmit i want to send array (fetchExcluded) but object checkboxes from useState i get empty object inside handleSaveOparation function.

please tell me how can I get data inside handlesubmit

```
  const defaultValues = {
      sum: '',
    };
      const {
        handleSubmit,
        control,
        watch,
        setValue,
        formState: { errors, isValid },
      } = useForm<OperationsData>({ defaultValues, resolver: yupResolver(schema), mode: 'onSubmit' });  
    const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState({});
    const fetchExcluded = useMemo(
      () => Object.entries(checkboxes)?.map(([k, v]) => ({ id: k, included: v })),
      [checkboxes],
   );
    
      console.log('fetchExcluded', fetchExcluded);//[{id:1,included:true}]
      console.log('checkboxes', checkboxes);//{1:true}
      const handleSaveOperation = useCallback(
handleSubmit((data) => {
            const { sum } = data;
            console.log('checkboxes', checkboxes);//{}
            console.log('fetchExcluded', fetchExcluded);//[]
       
          }),
        [checkboxes, date, fetchExcluded, handleSubmit],
      );

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSaveOperation}>...formComponents</form>
)
```

Comment: where do you set checkboxes?

Comment: checkboxes i get from backend. but it is not important. please see my console.log . it is empty only inside handleSubmit

Comment: try to use "useCallback" instead of "useMemo" for handleSubmit

Comment: I first used useCallBack but it didn't work

Comment: did you used it correctli? it should be just function: ` const handleSaveOperation= useCallback(()=>const {sum} = data......` without the callback you have there now

Comment: i changed the code. You can view?

Comment: Yes i can see it, but your callback should be without that "handleSubmit" function. Just use it to define that function: `const handleSaveOperation = useCallback((data)=> *something to do with submit data*`

Comment: Sorry maybe i am telling bs... did you tried to used it without callback or memo?

Comment: did but again I get an empty array

Comment: Yes. but I don't know why I get an empty array. this is very strange behavior